# NSFetchedResultsController and my TableView structure

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a tableView controller with two sections.  The first section has a couple of input fields and is not really displaying core data.  The second section displays items from a database saved with Core Data.

I have an `NSFetchedResultsController` and I serve up data for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` as follows.  For section = 0, I manually serve up the appropriate input fields, and for section = 1 I want to use `[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]`.  ()  However, since the fetched results controller only knows about one section, this doesn't work.

I know I can create a new IndexPath with section = 0, and then feed that to the `NSFetchedResultsController`.  Is that the preferred solution or is there another way to 'tell' the `NSFetchedResultsController` what to expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is to translate the `NSIndexPath` objects passed into the various `UITableViewDataSource`/`UITableViewDelegate` methods into index paths appropriate for your `NSFetchedResultsController`. I'd recommend adding a method to your class that does this.

The return values from this method will match the section numbers the `NSFetchedResultsController` uses. Also,  if in the future you end up needing a second header section for whatever reason, it's easy enough to adjust your method to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need to tell it anything?  In the delegate methods, just offset the section index by one and you should be fine.

You can create your own `NSIndexPath` instance to pass into the `NSFetchedResultsController` to resolve this issue.

### Update

If you want to have two sections then yes that is the right answer.  However I would consider putting your input fields into the table header instead of a section.  That would be a cleaner answer in my opinion.

Comment: right...my question was "is creating a new `NSIndexPath` the best method or is there a better way?"  apparently not, judging by the lack of commentary.